# What would be the correct status code for redirecting from a valid endpoint to another valid endpoint based on the request?

Tags: javascript, express, rest

I have two entities, projects and proposals. A proposal can be in 3 different states: pending, approved and rejected. A project has an associated proposal which has been previously approved. The endpoint for a proposal /proposals/:id allows a PATCH request to modify the proposal's state. I also have a different endpoint for projects /projects and a POST request creates a new project. I want to reject PATCH requests that try to set the proposal's state to approved and instead redirect them to the /projects endpoint. What would be the right status code in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to reject PATCH requests that try to set the proposal's state to approved and instead redirect them to the /projects endpoint. What would be the right status code in this situation?

I don't believe there's a registered HTTP status code that has these semantics.

The normal mechanism for sharing "the other URL is interesting right now" is via the `Location` header; the semantics of the Location header is only defined for 201 and 3xx responses; 201 and 3xx are both of the category of "non-error status codes".

None of the status codes listed in the [HTTP PATCH error handling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789.html#section-2.2) specification define semantics for the `Location` header.

---

What I would normally expect to see instead is that the server returns an HTTP response using some Client Error (as described by the [HTTP PATCH specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789.html#section-2.2)), and the "representation containing an explanation of the error situation" would include all of the information that the client needs to proceed.

It might help to consider the analog on the web - we would choose a status code for the general purpose HTTP components (browser, caches, proxies....) to understand, and an HTML body for the browser to render that would explain to the human what's going on, with links to help get the human back on track.